# Ember 1.0, Ember Data beta 3: getting related model data with DS.FixturesAdapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationship

JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/IYiqifO/16/edit?html,js,output

I have three related models set up with fixtures from DS.FixturesAdapter and I'm trying to figure out how to access a related model's attributes from the parent model in a component. My template looks like this:

```
{{#each data}}
  <li>
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    {{#each responses}}
      {{text}}<br />
    {{/each}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

And I also have some code in the component like this:

```
data = @get('data').map (respondent) ->
  {
    name: respondent.get('name')
    responses: respondent.get('responses').map (r) -> r.get('text')
  }
```

but the data[n].responses is always an empty array. What do I need to do to a) get my handlebars template to populate with the response data; and b) get my `data` object to have correctly-filled `responses` arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the responses ids in the `Respondent` fixture:

```
App.Respondent.FIXTURES = [
    id: 1
    name: 'Ada Lovelace'
    responses: [1,2]
  ,
    id: 2
    name: 'Grace Hopper'
    responses: [3,4]
]
```

After this you will receive a error:

> Assertion failed: You looked up the 'responses' relationship on
>   '' but some of the associated records were
>   not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the
>   parent record, or specify that the relationship is async
>   (`DS.hasMany({ async: true })`)

Like the message describe you need to use the `async: true` in your `responses` property:

```
App.Respondent = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  responses: DS.hasMany('response', async: true )
```

In your template you will see the data, but in the `didInsertElement` when it's called, the `responses` association isn't loaded. This happen because the template is binding aware but didInsertElement isn't. So when the `responses` is loaded the template update but the didInsertElement isn't called. Because the `responses` association return a promise, you can get all the responses in a array, and use `Ember.RSVP.all` to know when all the responses is loaded:

```
 App.ShowRespondentsComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  didInsertElement: ->
    allResponses = []
    @get('data').forEach (respondent) =>
      allResponses.push respondent.get('responses')     
    Ember.RSVP.all(allResponses).then =>
      @respondentLoaded()
  respondentLoaded: ->        
    thisIsWhatIWant = @get('data').map (respondent) ->
      {
        name: respondent.get('name')
        responses: respondent.get('responses').map (r) -> r.get('text')
      }
    console.log thisIsWhatIWant
```

This is a jsbin with this working http://jsbin.com/IYiqifO/19/edit

Comment: What about 'Either make sure they are all loaded'? Is this possible?

Comment: If I actually have to do this, it is an excellent argument for throwing away Ember Data and starting over again.